# MariaDB: Custom data directory: Always need to keep /var/lib/mysql directory

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I installed MariaDB server 13.0 on Centos 7.0, disabled SELinux. I started the MariaDB server successfully. After that, I want to custom my database data directory. So here are my steps:

- step 1: backup `/var/lib/mysql` directory
- step 2: copy to another place: `cp -Rp /var/lib/mysql /disk1/mysql`
- step 3: modify `datadir` from `my.cfg.d/server.cfg`:  `datadir=/disk1/mysql`

Then I stop and start again the MariaDB server using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

Everything runs successfully. I can create a new database, a new table and I see it changes the data in the new path. However, if I remove all directory `/var/lib/MySQL`. I cannot start my server anymore.

Here is the log when running command `systemctl status mariadb.service`

> - mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.16 database server    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset:
>     disabled)   Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
>            `-custom.conf, migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-06-28 11:55:59 +07;
>     4s ago
>      Docs: man:mysqld(8)
>            https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/   Process: 23296 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER
>     $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process:
>     23281 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] &&
>     VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl
>     set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited,
>     status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 23277 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl
>     unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited,
>     status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 23296 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

My old database server, I can delete `/var/lib/mysql`. Please explain to me the reason why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change MySQL data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory)

Comment: It is doesn't duplicate. I provide more detail about database version, OS version, my steps, and point out detail what point I cannot successfully. Please look again carefully.

Comment: So if you think that this was not my downvote ;) and there is only one place where you have to change the location and that is described in article. The other thing it that is is more a Server related question. So you should try it on ServerFault.

Comment: "Cannot start" -- any error in the logs?

Comment: @RickJames I have fixed my problem by custom `mysql.sock` file path. I don't know why there is no tutorial discussing this. (and still successfully). Do you know why ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked *MySQL* log and it has a line with content:

`"cannot read file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"`

That is my old directory so I think I need to custom `mysql.sock`.

In `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/disk1/mysql/
socket=/disk1/mysql/mysql.sock
```

In `/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cfg`:

```
[client]
# we need to configure this. so when we type mysql -u user. mysql can look up socket's location.
socket=/disk1/mysql/mysql.sock
```

After that, I can run and connect successfully to my *MySQL* instance. I don't know why there is no tutorial point out this point. But this is a way I used to fix my problem.